# Haskell list to unitary sublist

Tags: list, haskell, sublist

I'm having problems turning a list to a unitary sublist

```
sublists :: [a] -> [[a]]
sublists [] = [[]]
sublists (x:xs) = [x:ys | ys <- sub] ++ sub
                    where sub = sublists xs
```

I need a function that given
sublists [True,False]
returns
[[True],[False]]  instead of [[True,False],[True],[False],[]]
But I just don´t know how and feel like punching my computer in the face.

I hope I am clear. Thanks!

Comment: hint: use `map`

Comment: If it is just a matter of wrapping it in lists, you can use `sublist = map pure`.

Answer (score 3):

So you want a function that converts `a` to `[a]`. Okay...

```
makeList = \x -> [x]
```

(why did I write it as a lambda? keep reading)

So you want a function that converts `a` to `[a]` within a list. Okay...

```
makeListsInList = map (\x -> [x])
```

done.

Comment: Actually, I need to turn a list **[True,False,True,False]** to a sublist made of lists of every element of the list. Should look like this **[[True], [False], [True], [False]]**

Comment: @Bartender94 that's what this does

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [**`pure :: Applicative f => a -> f a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:pure) to wrap values into a list, since the instance of `Applicative` for `[]` wraps elements in a singleton list.

So you can define your function as:

```
sublists :: [a] -> [[a]]
sublists = map pure
```

For example:

```
Prelude> sublists [True, False, False, True]
[[True],[False],[False],[True]]
```